# Poor performance in TensorFlow

Tags: 16.04, performance, macbook-pro

Fully updated out of box Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is much slower than MacOS X in CPU-based training on TensorFlow on MacBook Pro Late 2013 (i7-4960HQ), up to 3-6x.

During training, CPU fan does not spin up, but spins during Geekbench (good performance)

Disabling Intel Powerclamp did not help.